# Green blocks instead of sequences in premiere timeline

Tags: premiere

Instead of sequences of shots/audio clips, my timeline shows solid green blocks.
How do I display these blocks in sequences, i.e. with each shot/audio clip showing as a small block?

Comment: Hello Guy. Welcome to GDSE. Please, please, **please** never use all caps on this site, or anywhere on the internet. It reads like yelling the reader in the face and at least here that is considered very rude.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot, and some more detail about what you're doing. Did you receive the project from someone else? How were the sequences made?